# ftp_mkdir(): OOPS: malloc

Tags: laravel, ftp, malloc, vsftpd, flysystem

I am getting this error on file upload `ftp_mkdir(): OOPS: malloc`, and I can't upload a base64 image on FTP server

my client is Flysystem on Laravel framework and my FTP server is `Vsftpd`